# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' Train Data

Tags: python

Could you help me find out the issue is the below loop  of a function to train the dataset.
I have one column "count" with datatype float32, the whole function works well but fails in the `append` line
Data:

```
Count
1.0
2.0
3.8
4.7
9.0
```

```
x,y=train_x, train_y
_x, _y = [], []
for i in range(len(y) - steps):
    **_y.append([y.iloc[i + steps].values])**
    _y = np.array(_y).astype(np.float32)
```

Another Issue: with mapping

```
x_train, x_test = train_x, test_x
    # Columns to be embedded: map to range [0, # values)
for cat in categorical:
    
    raw_vals, val_map = np.unique(x_train[cat]), {}
    for i in range(len(raw_vals)):
        val_map[raw_vals[i]] = i
    x_train.loc[:,cat] = x_train.loc[:,cat].map(val_map)
    x_test.loc[:,cat] = x_test.loc[:,cat].map(val_map)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy arrays don't have `.append()`, and you're casting the list to one after the first iteration.

You'll need to move the cast to an numpy array outside the loop:

```
x, y = train_x, train_y
_x, _y = [], []
for i in range(len(y) - steps):
    _y.append([y.iloc[i + steps].values])
_y = np.array(_y).astype(np.float32)  # <-- moved outside the loop
```

Comment: thanks completely missed that. I have another issue with map, i think receiving a warning ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1745: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead```. I have updated the in the main question

Comment: That's a different question that's not related to this one. Please accept this answer if it helped you in this particular question and ask that other, Pandas-related question separarely.